# Indexing combinations of a list

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I have a list that I compare its permutations (excluding with itself). For example, let's say I have a list R = {1,2,3,4,5}. I have the output as such O = {12,13,14,15,23,24,25,34,35,45}. Now here's the problem. I have to compare the output with the expected output which I have stored it in a list (which is the same as O). But I do not know how to index O[?] in such a way.
Here's my code to compare the array.

```
int [] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int [] expected = new int[]{3,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,8,9};
for(int i=0; i<arr.length - 1; i++){
      for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
           int temp = arr[i] + arr[j];
           if(temp == expected[?]){
                 #logic
           }
       }
 }
```

How can I index `expected[~]`? Thank you.

Here's a chart that I was analyzing:

```
i   |   j   |   index
0       1         0
0       2         1
0       3         2
0       4         3
1       2         4
1       3         5
1       4         6
2       3         7
2       4         8
3       4         9
```

Comment: what do you mean by "compare the output with the expected output"?

Comment: How is your expected output `{3,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,8,9}` when you said output should be `O = {12,13,14,15,23,24,25,34,35,45}` ?

Comment: O is the combinations {f(1,2), f(1,3) ... f(n-1,n-1)} with my function being (a+b) in this case. Let's say I'm running a test case where the "expected output" is given to me, and I need to compare this to the expected.

Comment: The algorithm for the general case of (i,j) is now provided.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven - I believe if you keep an index counter nested in the j loop, it will keep the sequence you desire... pls confirm

```
int [] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int [] expected = new int[]{3,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,8,9};
int index = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length - 1; i++){
  for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
       int temp = arr[i] + arr[j];
       if(temp == expected[index++]){
             #logic
       }
   }
 }
```

EDIT:  Here is the algorithm for a generic (i,j), where N is the max value of i.

```
    int [] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int [] expected = new int[]{3,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,8,9};
    int N = arr.length;
    for(int i=0; i<N - 1; i++){
      for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++){
           int temp = arr[i] + arr[j];
           if(temp == expected[getIndex(i,j,N)]){
                 #logic
           }
       }
     }
}

public static int getIndex(int i, int j, int N) {
    return S(N) - S(N-i) + j-i -1;
}

public static int S(int N) {
    return N * (N - 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: This was my final solution but I was wondering if it was able to be calculated by (i,j).

Comment: I thought about that as well.  Yes, if you did not already have this i,j loop, and randomly wanted the index of a given i, j, there is an algorithm, but since you have a perfect chance to use index++, this turns out to be the best.  Are you interested in the algorithm anyway?

Comment: Yes please. I'm interested. Thank you.